# How to make config.txt file properly readable in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a switch configuration with me in config.txt file .I have opened this file into tcl with `set fd [open config.txt r]` and and o/p of `puts $fd` ,

```
switchport
switchport access vlan 333
switchport mode access
switchport port-security
switchport port-security maximum 5
```

Now I want to parse this o/p to another file called newconfig.txt and it should look like following,

```
switchport

switchport access vlan 333

switchport mode access

switchport port-security

switchport port-security maximum 5
```

Can anybody tell me how to this as this file is very large and I want to make more readable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Care to explain what does "o/p" stand for? "Output"?

Comment: I'd prefer making it readable by only adding *some* newlines, e.g., keeping consecutive `port-security` lines packed tightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want the resulting file to contain all lines from the source file separated by blank lines.  This can be done by just appending an extra newline character (`\n`) to each line from the source file and writing it out to the resulting file, like this:

```
set in [open config.txt]
set out [open newconfig.txt w]

while {[gets $in line] >= 0} {
   append line \n
   puts $out $line
}
close $in
close $out
```

Answer (score 0):

I think alternative way may be:

```
set in    [open config.txt]
set out   [open newconfig.txt w]
set data  [read $in]
puts $out [join [split $data "\n"] "\n\n"]
close $in
close $out
```

This will not add extra new line to the last line in the file :)